# How to validate form input fields using Ant design framework in react application

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am trying to validate the form input field with decimal values, if the entered value is not number or decimal it should show error message, so far I have tried the below code example which is not validating characters and special character.

I would like to show error message when user enters, any other character than number and decimal

```
function position() {
   const { dispatch } = useContext(store);
    const [isDisable, setCheckBoxDisable] = useState(false)

    const onApply = (values) => {
        console.log('Success:', values);
        dispatch({
            type: "updateGPSCoordinates",
            latitude: values.latitude,
            longitude: values.longitude,
            altitude: values.altitude
        });
    };

return (
        <div>
            <div className="homepage-widget-header">
               <Form
                        {...layout}
                        className="gps-coordinates-form"
                        onFinish={onApply}

                    >
                        <Form.Item
                            label={GpsConstants.LATITUDE}
                            name="latitude"
                            initialValue="25.328380"
                            rules={[
                                {
                                    required: true,
                                    message: 'Please enter latitude!',
                                },
                            ]}
                        >
                            <Input />
                        </Form.Item>

                        <Form.Item
                            label={GpsConstants.LONGITUDE}
                            name="longitude"
                            initialValue="51.435989"
                            rules={[
                                {
                                    required: true,
                                    message: 'Please enter longitude!',
                                },
                            ]}

                        >
                            <Input />
                        </Form.Item>

                        <Form.Item
                            label={GpsConstants.ALTITUDE}
                            name="altitude"
                            initialValue="0.0"
                            rules={[
                                {
                                    required: true,
                                    message: 'Please enter altitude!',
                                },
                            ]}

                        >
                            <Input />
                        </Form.Item>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default GPSPosition
```

Thanks in advance
Appreciate quick help

Comment: Have you considered using [`InputNumber`](https://ant.design/components/input-number/)?

Comment: Hi, meaning instead of <Input /> i should be using <InputNumber /> ?

Comment: Yes, `InputNumber` already enforces that the input should be a numeric type (with decimal support). You can refer to the component's API if you need to control precision support, etc. If you really want to use `Input` though, you'll need to add a RegEx validation rule, something along the lines of: `{pattern: /^\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/, message: "Please enter a number or decimal"}`

Comment: Thanks great, <InputNumber> solved my problem. Thanks for another solution as well